# Pressure well tank and pressure switch installed

Tags: water, water-pressure, well

I just installed a new 32 gal well pressure tank as well as a new pressure switch regulator psi 40/60. I set pressure switch at 37. When I turn on the breakers to well pump, water and the pressure switch, the hot water heater started dispersing hot water from the relief valve. Why  or what would cause this to happen? Please help

Comment: Either a mistake in the settings or the relief valve has failed/weaken at the same time.  Did you bleed/have faucets open, the water system for air in the pipes/tank?

Comment: Lets start with a proper diagnosis. We can all guess at what's causing this, but without more info, it's just guesses. Make and model of the new WH would help a lot.   Most water heaters have a drain valve at the bottom with typical garden hose threads,  Get a pressure gauge , probably in the garden section or plumbing section of a big box store, put it on the drain valve, turn it on and see what the actual pressure is.  Let us know.

Comment: The pump should not be running

Comment: Probably **a wiring error,** barring bizarre failure modes. Pump not shutting off when it should will make excess pressure which will make a pressure relief valve open. I assume you precharged the presure tank to 37PSI, rather than "setting the pressure switch" to 37PSI which is what you wrote. You can [edit] to clarify or correct. You can also edit to include pictures. Clear pictures of the wiring connections might be very relevant. A well-pump system should have **at least** one permanently mounted pressure gauge on the water side.

Comment: and another guess, the overpressure valve is malfunctioning, you can find that out buy measuring the actual pressure, by connecting a hose to the boiler drain with pressure gauge on the other end

Comment: One more comment... When you replaced the tank and switch, did you add a check valve?  If so, does the WH have an expansion tank?   If not, you need one.   I had a rental that didn't have one.  The water company installed new meters with check valves.  Then, after lots of hot water usage, the relief valve would start releasing hot water.  The pressure gauge showed about 110 psi, so the valve was doing it's job.  Adding an expansion tank cured the problem.  But again, first things first: let's get some pressure readings.